# React Native with Xcode 13 throws: Error Analyzing App Version

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode13

I'm having problems uploading my app version since I upgraded Xcode to 13.3.1

The compilation succeeds as always, but when I'm doing the process of uploading and distributing to the App Store I get this screen with no explanation:

[image: Error]

I have cleared the cache, clean the build, and changed the node version from 14 to 16 and I haven't been able to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I solved this by setting the Team to NONE and then back to the signing team.

This is under the Signing tab.